# Is there a method for averaging pixel coordinates for star pixel coordinates?

Tags: python, astronomy

I am trying to implement a star-tracking algorithm, and so I first have to determine which pixels represent stars in an image.

I did this by first opening the image and changing each pixel to either black or white based on its comparison to the threshold brightness (shown below). However, when running this code I realized that some of the stars had multiple corresponding pixels, and so I would like to find the "center" pixel for each star. What methods are there for this?

```
import pandas as pd 
import math
from PIL import Image
from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("src/data.csv")
register_heif_opener()
img = Image.open("src/sample_star.heic")

threshold = 200
for x in range(img.width):
    for y in range(img.height):
        pixel = img.getpixel((x, y))
        brightness = (pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2]) / 3
        if brightness < threshold:
            img.putpixel((x, y), 0)
        else:
            img.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))

img.show()
```

Comment: Why don't you use the method you mentioned in the title? (Yes, it exists)

Comment: I'm not sure how to average them. Given a list of pixel coordinates that are the color white, how should I go about finding "center" points for each cluster corresponding to a star?

Comment: Use the original brightness of each blob to calculate the centroid.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about determining each blob. Would it be via some clustering algorithm?

Comment: If you want to show the solution, post an answer, don't edit it into the question!

Comment: Note that you'd likely be much faster converting the image into a numpy array and using vectorised operations.   That said I'm not sure why you're clustering rather than just thresholding the image.  Clustering seems overkill for an image that I'd expect to be mostly dark